# Clojure Multi Maps

Tags: clojure

Very simple + silly question:

Does clojure provide multi maps? I currently have something like this:

```
(defn wrap [func]
  (fn [mp x]
    (let [k (func x)]
      (assoc mp k
             (match (get mp k)
               nil [x]
               v (cons v x))))))

(defn create-mm [func lst]
  (reduce (wrap func) {} lst))
```

Which ends up creating a map, where for each key, we have a vector of all elements with that key. However, it seems like multi maps is a very basic data structure, and I wonder if clojure has it built-in.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think this is really necessary as a distinct type, as Clojure's flexibility allow you to quickly make your own by just using maps and sets.  See here:

http://paste.lisp.org/display/89840

### Edit (I should have just pasted this in since it's so small)

Example Code (Courtesy Stuart Sierra)

```
(ns #^{:doc "A multimap is a map that permits multiple values for each
  key.  In Clojure we can represent a multimap as a map with sets as
  values."}
  multimap
  (:use [clojure.set :only (union)]))

(defn add
  "Adds key-value pairs the multimap."
  ([mm k v]
     (assoc mm k (conj (get mm k #{}) v)))
  ([mm k v & kvs]
     (apply add (add mm k v) kvs)))

(defn del
  "Removes key-value pairs from the multimap."
  ([mm k v]
     (let [mmv (disj (get mm k) v)]
       (if (seq mmv)
         (assoc mm k mmv)
         (dissoc mm k))))
  ([mm k v & kvs]
     (apply del (del mm k v) kvs)))

(defn mm-merge
  "Merges the multimaps, taking the union of values."
  [& mms]
  (apply (partial merge-with union) mms))

(comment
  (def mm (add {} :foo 1 :foo 2 :foo 3))
  ;; mm == {:foo #{1 2 3}}

  (mm-merge mm (add {} :foo 4 :bar 2))
  ;;=> {:bar #{2}, :foo #{1 2 3 4}}

  (del mm :foo 2)
  ;;=> {:foo #{1 3}}
)
```

Extra test for the case pointed out in the comments:

```
(comment
  (-> {} (add :a 1) (del :a 1) (contains? :a))
  ;;=> false
)
```

Comment: I'll add that I have no idea the relative performance versus [Google Guava's MultiMap](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap), but since Clojure has pretty good Java interop, it might be easy enough to just wrap it if that's what you're after.

Comment: It's probably a good idea to copy that code into your answer (with the appropriate attributions etc), so that your answer stands alone just in case that link goes dead.

Comment: Note that `(-> {} (add :a 1) (del :a 1) (contains? :a) ;=> true`, which would surprise many users. A small modification to `del` would fix that.

Comment: Indeed, paste.lisp.org has been disabled.